# Making Asynchronous Service Calls in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make asynchronous service-call in my android app using AsyncTask Class, but for each and every service call in my activity i need to have a subclass in my Application which Extends AsyncTask. Can anyone Suggest me a better way of doing this???

In My Scenario Service Calls have different return-type,then i need to return an object for all service calls and typecast it according, Is there any better way of doing this ???

Answer (score 1):

Is it a service you wrote? If so, you could make the service itself asynchronous so that you can make calls on it that return instantaneously and later get notified via a callback. That would remove the need for the AsyncTasks on your Activity.

If you can't change the Service, one thing you can do is have a background worker thread that's responsible for interacting with the Service, and you post messages to it from the main thread using a Handler. The worker thread uses another Handler to deliver the results back to the UI thread once each work item is finished.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: Ya its a service i wrote, but i need to handle at Client Side.

Comment: Can u share me an example if possible so that it would be easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

["AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) sez the droid.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare the AsyncTask as an inner class of your activity.  Declare this class once in it's own scope, and you can use it from anywhere.  As far as the data to pass in and out, you can make the first parameter a String or Uri and pass in the request data, and you can use an internal listener object in the AsyncTask that can be set by the activity to receive a call back when onPostExecute fires.

**EDIT**

I made a gist to demonstrate the simplest version of this.  Using the example AsyncTask-derived class, you can reuse this one class throughout your entire app and pass it all of your endpoints and receive the result inside your activities (or anywhere else you need to make your service calls).  If you need to make this more extensive, you can just change the input object from a String to some more complex data structure containing anything you need to pass to your service call (post params, http method, etc) and you can change the signature of the OnPostExecuteListener interface if you want to return structured data and not just the raw result

https://gist.github.com/80c59fb70e195ca142bb

Comment: But I should have different implementations for each service call in the method of AsyncTask i.e, doinbackground() & postexecute().

Comment: You can pass in a data structure to doInBackground by setting the first generic type of the AsyncTask.  For example extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> will take a String[] argument to doInBackground which you pass in to the execute() method.  The third param is what you return from doInBackground and receive in onPostExecute.  This can be the service payload as a string or byte array, or it can be a common base class that your data objects or collections derive from.