# Make Asynchronous Calls to a Service (Android)

Tags: android

Right now I have an Activity and a local Service. I need to be able to call a service method asynchronously from the activity. The only ways I know of communicating between a service and an activity is through Intents, binding, and AIDL.

I tried binding, but bound service calls are synchronous.

Using intents (modifying the intent passed to startService) doesn't work either because onStartCommand is called on the main thread.

I'd rather not resort to AIDL because it seems rather complicated. Any alternatives I'm missing?

btw [Making Asynchronous Service calls in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461741/making-asynchronous-service-calls-in-android) does not answer my question

**PROLOGUE**

Following [CommonWare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24517957/1852456) I decided to use a service with a ThreadPoolExecuter

Comment: Services in general are synchronous, because they work on the UI thread just like activities.  Does your service have a thread?

Comment: The [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) says that services are for "long-running operations in the background". How would they do that without a thread? Am I using the wrong type of service?

Comment: "How would they do that without a thread?" -- just because something is designed for a role does not mean that it handles everything involved in that role. A box may be designed to serve as a shipping carton, but that does not mean that the box fills itself, seals itself shut with tape, etc. It is *your job* to arrange for work in a `Service` to happen on a background thread, whether by using an existing service class that offers this feature (e.g., `IntentService`) or by forking your own background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only ways I know of communicating between a service and an activity is through Intents, binding, and AIDL.

AIDL *is* binding. AIDL makes it possible to bind between apps.

> I tried binding, but bound service calls are synchronous.

Make the call in a background thread, then.

> Using intents (modifying the intent passed to startService) doesn't work either because onStartCommand is called on the main thread.

The service can use a background thread, then. For example, an `IntentService` supplies a background thread, passing the `Intent` delivered originally to `onStartCommand()` on to your `onHandleIntent()` method.

> Any alternatives I'm missing?

None that avoid the background thread.

Comment: this is what I mean by [binding](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). How could make an asynchronous intent handler without using an IntentService?

Comment: @woojoo666: "How could make an asynchronous intent handler without using an IntentService?" -- do what `IntentService` does and use a background thread. For example, you could have a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and `onStartCommand()` to use a thread from the pool to process the command.

Comment: nevermind I misunderstood what an IntentService was. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, an IntentService did not work for me because I needed persistent objects and IntentServices close after all jobs are finished. Instead, I used a service with an [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), which I made to run all my service requests on a single background thread.

`handleMessageHelper` handles all requests on a background thread. I use a [`Messenger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html) to recieve requests, and use a custom `Runnable` to pass the `msg` to my `handleMessageHelper` method

### MyService.java (snippet)

```
ExecutorService background = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

//handles messages from client
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        background.execute(new MessengerRunnable(msg));
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
    
    class MessengerRunnable implements Runnable {
        
        public Message msg;

        public MessengerRunnable(Message m) {
            super();
            msg = m;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handleMessageHelper(msg);
        }
        
    }
}

//called from handleMessage in IncomingHandler
//should be run on `background` ExecutorService
public void handleMessageHelper(Message msg) {
    
    Log.d("CASE: ","" + msg.what);
    
    switch (msg.what) {
    case SET_ACCOUNT:
        Bundle b = msg.getData();
        String accountName = b.getString("accountName");
        if (accountName != null) {
            setAccount(accountName);
        }
        break;
    }
}

final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
```